# Is there an alternative to lightbox / fancy box / slimbox that does not require a doctype declaration?

Tags: lightbox, doctype, fancybox, slimbox

I am forced to work within a rubbish IDE that creates survey webpages, therefore I cannot control the doctype of the pages (it's not a great piece of software, in fact I hate it but have no choice, and it adheres to no standard doctype, it adheres to no standard anything!).

I want to produce a pretty popup on my pages, but cannot use lightbox or any alternative that I can find as these all require a doctype declaration.  My popups look great in except IE (naturally).  If I insert a doctype declaration into the page the popups work, but all sorts of other things on the page don't, inputs and so on.

Can anyone suggest an alternative plugin I can use, or some sort of hack I can put in my page to overcome this problem?  e.g. is there a vanilla doctype that means nothing, or perhaps a way of fooling lightbox that a doctype exists when it doesn't?

Thanks for any suggestions!

CJ

Comment: It's not a case of the lightbox requiring the DocType; it's a case of the browser requiring a DocType so that it knows how to render the lightbox correctly.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution yet. I am wanting to add light box functionality to an of-the-shelf product that declares no DocType. When I add a DocType, all the Javascript functionality of the application breaks - and ofcourse I have no control over this.

Comment: Fortunately the IDE I have to use has 'upgraded' to use a DocType so I've been able to make fancybox work.  It's really a flaw in the web pages it was producing, but it's dragged itself into the year 1999 :/

Good luck in your quest!

Answer (score -2):

yes, visit http://lakhlaniprashant.blogspot.com/2008/12/creating-modal-popup-in-html-4-using.html

Comment: Sorry - i don't see which section you mean, there is nothing there that I can see to suggest what to do when no doctype is present?